# FInding date gaps in R

Tags: r

I am using R and have a vector of dates as Day of Year (DOY) in which some days are missing. I want to find where these missing days are.

```
DOY <- c(1,2,5,6,7,10,15,16,17)
```

I want an output which tells me that missing days are between day:

```
2 to 5 
7 to 10
10 to 15
```

(Or the indices of these locations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rDOY <- range(DOY); 
rnDOY <- seq(rDOY[1],rDOY[2]) 
rnDOY[!rnDOY %in% DOY]
[1]  3  4  8  9 11 12 13 14
```

If instead you don't want the mssing days and do wnat the beginnings and ends of the missing items:

```
> DOY[ diff(DOY)!=1]
[1]  2  7 10
> DOY[-1] [ diff(DOY)!=1]
[1]  5 10 15
```