# R: address data gaps in a (yearly) data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking for output which includes all cases of my (large) `data.table` that are missing in between available observations.

```
DT <- data.table(country=c(rep("DE",10),rep("AT",10)),time=rep(2001:2010,2), value=rnorm(20))
DT[country=="DE" &time %in% c(2001,2005,2006),"value"] <- NA
DT[country=="AT" &time %in% c(2003,2008,2009,2010),"value"] <- NA
```

I want to write a function which allows me to create a `data.table` with only `DE` in `2005` & `2006` and `AT` in `2003`. Building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719251/finding-date-gaps-in-r), I am almost there, for one country it looks like this:

```
test <-DT[country=="DE"]
range <- range(test[!is.na(value),time])
sequence <- seq(range[1],range[2]) 
sequence[!sequence %in% test[!is.na(value),time]]
```

And now I want to make a function out of this to use across `country` with `data.table`s `by` option. Here is my non-working example:

```
#function to find datagaps (NA's) in a data.table (you still have to apply by group):
#x is the name of the column which specifies your frequency (such as year or date)
#y is the name of the column which has the NA's you're looking for
#data is a data.table

findgaps <- function(x,y,data){
range <- range(data[!is.na(y),x])
sequence <- seq(range[1],range[2]) 
return(sequence[!sequence %in% data[!is.na(y),x]])
}
DT[findgaps(time,year,DT),.(country,time,value),by=country)]
```

My best guess is that the function does not return something sensible for `data.table` to subset with in the filter, correct? Should that become a F,F,F,T,F,F,F... vector somehow as the output of the function? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Desired Output could look like this:

```
output <- data.table(country=c("DE","DE","AT"), time=c(2005,2006,2003), value=c("NA","NA","NA"))
```

in the end I want to do something with this, like an intrapolation. So any way to specifically address those rows in `DT` would be fine for me.

Comment: What is your desired output? Could you provide it as a data.table?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps:

```
DT[, { r = rleid(is.na(value))
       idx = r > r[1] & r < tail(r, 1) & is.na(value)
       .(time = time[idx], value = NA)
     }
   , by = country]
```

Comment: I think this returns every country even if it has no missings, right?

Comment: also, do you know how to extend the list with time and value by other variables that might be in the data.frame? I was thinking replacing `value=NA` with `names(Data)[!names(Data) %in% c("time")]` but that doesnt work...

Comment: somehow, I can't manage to combine this with other columns I would like to be returned for this selection...

Comment: @PeterPan just merge (or join) the results back onto your original data.table.