# Find missing dates in a date frame dates in it

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with 15 dates in it, in order and in sequence, is a month/date/year date, how can I find what dates are missing? For example if it jumps from 2/3/2018 to 2/5/2018 the result will be a dataframe with the value 2/4/2018 and others it finds missing? The original data frame has only one column called date.

Comment: See this question on finding gaps in a vector: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719251/finding-date-gaps-in-r

Comment: thanks I followed the example and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try also this, to have the full sequence of dates:

```
data <-data.frame(Dates = as.Date(c("2018/10/10","2018/10/13","2018/10/31")))

data_ <- data.frame(Dates_all =
                    seq(min(data$Dates), max(data$Dates), by="days"))

data_
    Dates_all
1  2018-10-10
2  2018-10-11
3  2018-10-12
4  2018-10-13
5  2018-10-14
6  2018-10-15
7  2018-10-16
8  2018-10-17
9  2018-10-18
10 2018-10-19
11 2018-10-20
12 2018-10-21
13 2018-10-22
14 2018-10-23
15 2018-10-24
16 2018-10-25
17 2018-10-26
18 2018-10-27
19 2018-10-28
20 2018-10-29
21 2018-10-30
22 2018-10-31
```

To find the missing dates as vector:

```
data_[!data_$Dates_all %in% data$Dates,]
 [1] "2018-10-11" "2018-10-12" "2018-10-14" "2018-10-15" "2018-10-16" "2018-10-17"
 [7] "2018-10-18" "2018-10-19" "2018-10-20" "2018-10-21" "2018-10-22" "2018-10-23"
[13] "2018-10-24" "2018-10-25" "2018-10-26" "2018-10-27" "2018-10-28" "2018-10-29"
[19] "2018-10-30"
```